# Print Non-Duplicate Integer Element in Array using Java without using inbuilt methods

Tags: java, arrays, loops, duplicates, logic

```
 public class Exercise {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] my_array = {1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2};

        for (int i = 0; i < my_array.length-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < my_array.length; j++)
            {
                if ((my_array[i] == my_array[j]) && (i != j))
                {
                    System.out.print(my_array[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Input:   {1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2}
Output: {1, 7}

I need to print only non-duplicate element in array without using inbuilt methods as above example.Kindly help.Thanks in advance

Tried some as below but its not working for all the inputs:

```
public class Exercise {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
int[] my_array = {1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2};
int[] unique = new int[20];
int uniqueLength = 0;

outerloop:for (int i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < uniqueLength; j++)
{
if (my_array[i] == unique[j])
{
continue outerloop;
}
}
unique[uniqueLength] = my_array[i];
System.out.println(my_array[i]);
uniqueLength++;
}
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
public class Exercise {

   public static void main(String []args) {
      int[] my_array = {1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2};

      for (int i = 0; i < my_array.length-1; i++)
         {
          boolean is_non_dupe = true;
          for (int j = 0; j < my_array.length; j++)
            {
             if ((my_array[i] == my_array[j]) && (i!=j))
              {
                is_non_dupe = false;
              }
           }
           if(is_non_dupe){
            System.out.println(my_array[i]); 
           }
     }
  } 
}
```

OP: {1,7}

Comment: Wow gotcha! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To only print non-duplicate numbers, the code is very similar to the code you showed, exception the `j` loop must iterate all values, and you need to move the print statement out of the `j` loop, so you can print when no duplicate is found, instead of printing the duplicates themselves.

```
int[] my_array = {1, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2};

for (int i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    boolean dup = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < my_array.length; j++) {
        if (i != j && my_array[i] == my_array[j]) {
            dup = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! dup) {
        System.out.println(my_array[i]);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
1
7
```